# rails database item are not listed in my index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

in my line item index page I write the code to list rows but it is not listed also there is no error

```
<% @line_items.each do |line_item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= line_item.phone_id %></td>
    <td><%= line_item.cart_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', line_item %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_line_item_path(line_item) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', line_item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

(it supposed to be listed but noting even there is no error )
here is my code in index page

error 2

actually my purpose add to cart thing I give a link which add to cart, in store index it supposed to add to cart but I got just white screen when I click add to cart
and in the book(agile we development with rails) it is button (bu I used link instead )However when I use button I got this Can't mass-assign protected attributes: phone
here is my controller

```
 def create
    @cart = current_cart
    phone = Phone.find(params[:phone_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:phone => phone)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
          format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,:notice => 'Line item was successfully created.' ) }
          format.xml { render :xml => @line_item,:status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and also here is my store index

```
<br />
 <div id="content" class="float_r">
            <h1>New Products</h1>
            <% @phones.each do |phone| %>
            <div class="product_box">
                <a href="productdetail.html"><%=image_tag( phone.image_url,class:'list_image') %></a>
                <h3><%= phone.model %></h3>
                <p class="product_price"><span class="product_price" ><%= number_to_currency(phone.price) %></span></p>
                <p class="add_to_card"><%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path(:phone_id => phone) %></p>
                <p  class="detail"><%= link_to 'details' , phone_path(phone) %></p>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

if it is link I got just white page
when it is button   this error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: phone

Comment: Please show your index action code. Either you don't actually have any line items or your index action is retrieving them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 2: add `attr_accessible :phone` to `models/line_item.rb`. [Here's why](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Comment: it works thank but still whan I change it to button I got diffrent page from when it is link path is same how could it be